# Python - drag file into .exe to run script

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, executable

I have a Python script that takes the directory path of a text file and converts it into an excel file. Currently I have it running as a console application (compiled with py2exe) and prompts the user for the directory path through raw_input().

How do i make it such that I can drag & drop my text file directly into the .exe of the python script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dropped file will be available as an element of `sys.argv`.